# Detail of proof from Tu, An Introduction to Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Reading currently Tu, An Introduction to Manifolds and at page $84$ he says that every tangent vector $X_p \in T_p(M)$ is the velocity vector of some $p$.

Then he goes and states the following

> For any point $p$ in a manifold $M$ and any tangent vector $X_p \in T_p(M)$, there are $\varepsilon > 0$ and a smooth curve $c: ]−\varepsilon,\varepsilon[ \to M$ such that $c(0) = p$ and $c′(0) = X_p$.

he then proves the result, but I'm left wondering what is so special about this $0$? Why cannot we consider any $c(x_0)$ and $c'(x_0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mathematical reason for this. You could reparametrize the curve to be a curve $\widetilde{c}(t):(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)\to M$ by defining $\widetilde{c}=c\circ \tau_{-x_0}$ where $\tau_{x_0}(y)=y-x_0$. This will have the same trajectory at $t=x_0$ as $c$ has at $t=0$.

People tend to use $0$ as an "initial" time, so we like to think of the point of interest $p\in M$ as being traversed at time $t=0$, but it is not important for conceptual reasons.